# Updating a resource meta-data using a GET request

Tags: api, rest

I have to develop a RESTful API to manage documents and their associations with users.
I have to keep track of every time an user has accessed one of the documents. This is particularly important on the first access, since I have to distinguish between 'Never read' and 'Already read' documents.

I was wondering whether a GET request on a path like /documents/{id} is allowed to update the 'lastUpdate' field on the database. I'm afraid it might violate the safe and idempotent constraints of a GET request, but it feels otherwise appropriate, especially since users might want to bookmark the URL.

What is the general consensus on such a requisite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem. In this case your intention with the GET request is to return data. You don't send any information about how to change the seen property. What really changes that property is an EVENT which is triggered by the GET request. This event can be part of the access control mechanism you use. For example [by XACML you can define such events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#Obligations).

But if you have problems with that, an alternative approach to send a PATCH, PUT or POST (depending on the API) with your client after every GET.